# PHP need help to filter a loggfile

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem is this I got a code that loops trough a loggfile then compares them to a treestructure and then gives them a id that correspond to the id in the structure. To not get a lot of bad traffic i sort out all the 302 and above.

The problem is now that i want some specific 302s to count that have a particular pagetype in the structure. This is not a big problem as I can just match the url in the loggfile against the url in the tree structure but some loggfiles does not use friendly url while the structure is in friendly url this creates a problem but I can just match the id in the query parameter with the id in the structure. I then make a string of all the ids that match the special pagetype that I want.

The problem is this I can not get the Mysql statement to work, it looks like this.

```
$sqlQ1 = "SELECT `lid` FROM logfile WHERE date = '$date' AND ´query´ IN '$check'";
```

A example query can look like this "id=4&epslanguage=sv" so I want to check only the id=X part.

It´s a kinda easy question really im just stuck and can not get it to work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is in your mysql database that you are querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Q is: How do I extract id from that part of a line?

> ".. so I want to check only the id=X part."

Once you have isolated that string then you can use:

```
$string = "id=4&abclang=sv";

parse_str($string);

echo $id; // 4
```

EDIT
In light of other responses:

```
$strings[] = "id=4&abclang=sv";
$strings[] = "id=45&abclang=en";

$vals = array();

foreach( $strings as $string){
parse_str($string);
$vals[] = $id ;
}

$in_clause = join(",", $vals) ;
 $sql = "SELECT lid FROM logfile WHERE something  IN ($in_clause) ";
echo $sql; // SELECT lid FROM logfile WHERE something IN (4,45)
```

Comment: I realise now that my question is very poorly formulated.. But the question boils down to this I want to be able to match the string of ids i have with the id in a query and not have to loop trough the whole loggfile but instead just ask one database question and get the result in form of all the unique lids that I have in my database. Then use the lids I get to sort out all the loggfile rows that I want to keep.

Comment: Thanks that helps some but the problem is this, my database question looks like this "SELECT lid FROM logfile WHERE query IN ('4,45');" I know there is rows in the logfile table that have 4 and 45 in the query but I get no results, I have tried with using wildcards for the IN but it does'nt work.

Comment: That sql snippet is incorrect. Where are those extra quote around 4, 45 coming from? Find that and get rid of them.

Comment: Are you extracting all the ids successfully? Did you echo out the finalised $sql string? Did you copy that echoed string out and post it into your database? Did that throw any sql errors? Give us a clue.

Comment: I am not getting any errors just no results. And I want to avoid to loop trough the whole logfile at all costs since it will be to consuming. So what I would want is to be able to do a SQL question that finds all the rows that have id=4 in its query. I tried using IN since I will have a string of ids but IN doesn't seem to support wildcards else I could do a " query IN (%id=4&%, %id=45&%);" but I can't get IN to work like that.

Comment: I have been thinking about doing a `WHERE query LIKE 'id=4&%' OR query LIKE 'id=45&%'` and so on, not sure how this would effect effeciency.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the IDs already and want to filter the MySQL query to just get these rows?

```
$check = Array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$check = implode(",", $check);
$sqlQ1 = "SELECT `lid` FROM logfile WHERE date = '$date' AND ´query´ IN ($check)";
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get the lids from the logfile table. The lids are unique and if I can get those the problem is solved, but my problem is this when the query is not just id=4 or id=45 it is id=45&lang=en&melon=tasty so I cant use IN, I dont want to loop trough the whole logfile database and explode on the id to just get the id as it will increase the processing time by to much.